# How to use object in an external js link in vue ccomponent?

Tags: javascript

I first successfully add an external js in my vue component like this

```js
let articleJs = document.createElement('script');
articleJs.setAttribute('src', 'https://example.js');
document.head.appendChild(articleJs);
```

and in that example js I tried like this:

```js
export const targetData = [1,2,3];
```

So now I want to use that targetData in my vue component, any one knows how?